# Android changes "spinner text"'s gravity after selecting from "listitem"

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-gravity

In my scenario, when I click on the spinner the values dropdown will pop with listview text items aligned to left. Now what I wanted is after selecting from the list item when it sets to the spinner value the text item should be right aligned.

Unable to find a solution.

Below is my spinner code

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new d4ValuesListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, sVals);

       dynamicSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

       dynamicSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                   int position, long id) {


               Log.v("item", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
               dynamicSpinner.setGravity(Gravity.END);
           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           }
       });
```

Below is my adapter code

```
  public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

   LayoutInflater inflater= ((FragmentChangeActivity) context).getLayoutInflater();
   View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
   TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinnervalues);
   label.setText(DayOfWeek[position]);
   sharedPrefrences =getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCE_FILENAME,Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
   int spinneritem = sharedPrefrences.getInt(Constants.SPINNER_LISTITEM, -1);
   if(spinneritem == position ){
       label.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.turquise_blue));
       label.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_color));
   }

   return row;
  }
```

Comment: You need to override getDropDownView() method to set text in left align for dropdown and for selected item to set text in center you need to override getView or getContentView method

Comment: @Vickyexpert  Thanks a lot..it worked.

Comment: Enjoy your coding and you can accept below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To format and manage drop values you need to override method
 **getDropDownView()**

and

For Selected Item you need to override **getView()** or **getContentView()** method, so it will work.